# Builds are not visible in TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

In my TestFlight, I have more than 50 builds for Internal & external testers as well.

Today I uploaded a new build ver 2.5.1 from Xcode (My last ver on Apple store is **2.5**). The build has been upload & I can see my build has been processed under '**Activity**' tab but when I am trying to load '**TestFlight**' tab, I am getting a blank screen as below, none of the builds are visible.

[image]

I have tried to open iTunesConnect on Safari, Chrome with the different type of user access (Admin, developer) but still getting the same screen.

Is this something wrong with Apple (I am trying from last 3 hours) side or I have to make any provision from my end.

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you try to upload build using application loader?

Comment: no.. I uploaded directly from Xcode, as usual, I did for all the builds.

Comment: Do a trick , upload two builds at same time , one from application loader , and one from xcode.one will definitely go

Comment: As I mentioned, The build has been uploaded & processed as well. I have more than 50 builds under testflight, if you look into the attached screenshot you can see none of them are visible today.

Comment: 1. When your build is successfully uploaded. You can not upload a build with same verion/build number. if you do not get this error then your build is not uploaded. 2. The xcode has very old error, sometimes its uploaded builds do not appear in itunes. even if error(1) is shown. i have faced this issue many times , i used application loader.

Comment: you image is blank... and loader is showing yp. after loader ends loading.. do yuo still see the blank screen?

Comment: Another solution. while uploading the build , from xcode. do not minimize xcode window.

Comment: Please check you developer account email id, When you build has been rejected by 0permission issue, then your build not show in test flight. My have faced same issue of my last build to upload test flight. I have not get permission form user for bluetooth, but my third party SDK was used bluetooth, then I issue was accord.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue and could only fix it by contacting Apple directly. I've requested a call through their "contact us" (on iTunes connect, not the main website) and got a call within a minute. 
After explaining to the attendant my case (mentioning that there's a javascript error on the developer console!) she immediately sent a ticket to the iTunes Connect team and it was fixed one day later.

Answer (score 1):

I had build problem regarding **Testflight**.Once I uploaded on testflight the build could not been appear for a day.So I had contact with apple guy.

https://developer.apple.com/contact/#!/topic/select

Raise your queries here, they will definitely resolve your problem.
Hope this link will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer,

I tried for the whole day but Testflight was not loading.

I did try after 10 hours in midnight and I found all my builds are visible & Testflight is loading.

I think there was some issue from Apple side & they did fix within a day.

I also found a link discussing the same issue

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308244/testflight-tab-doesnt-load-in-itunes-connect